# Strange behaviour drawing VectorDrawables on an Android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-vectordrawable

I'm new in using VectorDrawables in Android and need some help, because I have a behaviour I don't understand yet.

I have two vector assets for drawing a simple icon (rhombus). They are nearly identical, they only differ in the fillColor: one is black and the other white.
In my code I try to draw the first rhombus (color black) at a special position and afterwards the other rhombus (white) at the same position.
My assumption is that the white rhombus completely covers up the black rhombus, but I wonder why there is still a small "black border" visible from the rhombus behind.

Can anybody tell me what's the reason for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.
Boris

```
    private void drawVector(Canvas canvas, int resId, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);
        VectorDrawableCompat vectorDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext().getResources(), resId, null);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

First xml with color black:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200"
    >
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,100 L100,0 200,100 100,200Z"
      android:fillColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Second xml with color white:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200"
    >
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,100 L100,0 200,100 100,200Z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

Printing both vector drawabled at same position:

```
drawVector(canvas, R.drawable.ic_raute1, x, y, 200, 200)
drawVector(canvas, R.drawable.ic_raute2, x, y, 200, 200)
```

[VectorDrawable with "border"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Binww.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @boz g . I tried your code by copy pasting. There is no frame on my side, The one on the top covers the one below as expected.

Comment: Hi Oya, thanks for trying. I have added a picture how it looks on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Binww.jpg

Comment: Perhaps this is due to anti-aliasing? The edge could use a semi-transparent treatment to make it look smooth, so you'd be able to see some black through the white.

Comment: @BenP. I first tried to disable anti-aliasing, but it wasn't the problem. I found a solution. If I set strokeColor for second xml (white rhombus) explicitly to white and it works now:

Comment: ``` <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="200"
    >
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,100 L100,0 200,100 100,200Z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector> ```

Comment: Nevertheless thanks for your proposed solutions!